# USER PERMISSIONS in a list

Tags: permissions

So I am trying to create a document that will show each of the Call center reps their individual matrix for things such as call time and the number of calls etc.  So I have a list of 10 calls CTR reps and I want to post the list to SharePoint but I'm not wanting to have each of them see the others info.  I've tried so many ways to get this work but no luck... could someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

I'd split out the list per rep, then create one list per rep and import from spreadsheet--having each list permission edited so that only the rep can see his/her list. That's if you have a detailed list of each call and when and there are multiple items for each rep.

Or you can split the permissions based on a list item if it's just one list item per rep. Just go to the permissions of that list item in the drop-down.